# calling the REST url with empty path param

Tags: java, rest

Server: Wildfly 8

REST Packages: javax.ws.rs.*

While to try access the below rest service with 
`http://localhost:8070/RestSample-war/rest/bean/getall/sam` it works fine, but while try with empty path param as like
`http://localhost:8070/RestSample-war/rest/bean/getall/` , it throws below error

```
@GET
@Path("getall/{name: .*}")
@Produces("application/json")
public Object Getall(@PathParam("name") String customerName) {
  if(customerName !=null){
      //return specific customer detail
  }else{
     //return all customer detail
  }
}
```

**Error:**

```
17:18:04,637 WARN  [org.jboss.resteasy.core.ExceptionHandler] (default task-37) 
failed to execute: javax.ws.rs.NotFoundException: Could not find resource for 
full path: http://localhost:8070/RestSample-war/rest/bean/getall/
```

Comment: The better design would be to have two different methods that are mapped to the different urls.

Comment: @ThorstenSchiffer, ya your point is valid but in some cases it required, so i like to know why this regex solution is not working. But this solution is available in lot of stackoverflow question about empty path param in earlier 2012, 2013. Is this option is depricated ?

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try removing the whitespace

```
@Path("getall/{name:.*}")
```